# Erro 404 ao gravar um formulário - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

Sres, boa noite!

Estou utilizando a ferramenta wordpress a pouco tempo e me surgiu um problema que não consegui resolver.
Quando tento gravar um formulário no banco mysql aparece o erro 404. Gostaria de um auxilio sobre como corrigir

html:

```
<form action="teste.php" method="post">
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">
<br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<br>
Observação: <textarea name="observacao" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

php:

```
<?php
//aqui é só um exemplo para não rodar o script abaixo sem necessidade
if ((isset($_POST['email']))&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){

   //porta, usuário, senha, nome data base
   //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão
   $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "paroq110_pjn", "hrsist@20", "paroq110_pjn") or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados " . mysqli_error($conexao));

  //Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
  $nome = $_POST['nome']; 
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];

   $string_sql = "INSERT INTO pjn_teste (nome,email,observacao) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$observacao')";
   $insert_member_res = mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql);
   if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao)>0){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
       echo "<p>Teste ok</p>";
       echo '<a href="testimonianze.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
   } else {
       echo "Erro, não foi possível inserir no banco de dados";
   }
   mysqli_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados
}else{
    echo "Por favor, preencha os dados";
}

    mysql_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados 
?>
```

Detalhe: Inseri o php na raiz da pasta do tema em uso... Não sei se fiz corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Sem ter acesso a logs ou mais detalhes, eu diria que é alguma configuração no MySQL impedindo este accesso.

Para além disto, sugiro que não manipule diretamente a base de dados do WordPress e opte por utilizar a API que o próprio WordPress oferece para manipular o banco de dados, através da classe [`WPDB`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/). Também daria uma olhada na documentação sobre ganchos/[hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/), que são de dois tipos: ações/[actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) e filtros/[filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/).

Como mencionou que é novo em WordPress, diria que ler a [documentação para desenvolvedores](https://developer.wordpress.org/) sobre e testar como funcionam ações e filtros, será o melhor investimento no seu tempo se desejar aprender mais de WordPress, que é arquitetado para ser bastante customizado através destes ganchos.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no `<form action="teste.php" method="post">`
Repare que você está tentando acionar um arquivo teste.php sem colocar a URL completa de onde está esse arquivo. Por exemplo, se o seu arquivo está dentro da pasta do tema deveria estar como

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/teste.php" method="post">
```

onde o

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/
```

aponta para a pasta do seu tema ativo.

Essa resposta serve apenas para a questão do erro 404, a forma como quer salvar os dados no banco de dados, não é uma boa prática no WordPress. Recomendo pesquisar sobre add_post_meta() e wpdb.